# How to use condition while selecting hosts in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Below is my playlist. My doubt is, How do I use the IP which  get from `{{ hostvars['localhost']['srv'] }}` and `{{ hostvars['localhost']['srv1'] }`
to the hosts with condition.

I wish to use like if telnet to server is successful then in next hosts, it should use `{{ hostvars['localhost']['srv'] }}` and if server1 telnet failed then hosts should get `{{ hostvars['localhost']['srv1'] }` and so on.

I tried to use OR in hosts but it is not working.

Is there any way to get this working?

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks: 
    - name: Telnet to server1
      shell: 'telnet 10.2.0.150 8080'
      register: pass
      ignore_errors: yes

    - set_fact:
        ip={{pass.cmd| regex_findall('[0-9./]+') | list}}
      register: ip_result

    - set_fact:
        srv={{ip_result.ansible_facts.ip[0]}}
      register: srv

    - debug: msg={{srv}}

    - name: Telnet to server2
      shell: "telnet 10.2.0.187 8080"
      register: pass1
      ignore_errors: yes
      when: "'Connection refused' in pass.stderr or 'Connection timed out' in pass.stderr"

    - set_fact:
        ip1={{pass1.cmd| regex_findall('[0-9./]+') | list}}
      register: ip1_result
      when: "'Connection refused' in pass.stderr or 'Connection timed out' in pass.stderr"

    - set_fact:
        srv1={{ip1_result.ansible_facts.ip[0]}}
      register: srv1
      when: "'Connection refused' in pass.stderr or 'Connection timed out' in pass.stderr"

    - debug: msg={{srv1}}
      when: "'Connection refused' in pass.stderr or 'Connection timed out' in pass.stderr"


- hosts: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['srv'] }}" or "{{ hostvars['localhost']['srv1'] }}"
  tasks:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by using jinja query.

`- hosts: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['srv'] if 'Connection closed' in hostvars['localhost']['pass']['stderr'] else hostvars['localhost']['srv1']}}"`

Tested it by stopping first server, then it took second servers and executed task to that server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change an inventory on-fly (you can't add or remove hosts from playbooks). But if all your hosts already are in an inventory, you can use group_by module to create groups inside plays.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/group_by_module.html

Comment: all the IP's getting by `{{ hostvars['localhost']['srv'] }}` is already in inventory , but I need to use it condition wise, not sure how `group_by` could be useful in this.

Comment: You can add specific hosts to a specific group (f.e. `special_group`) and assign a play to that group.